# Wordpress resize image with custom file name

Tags: php, wordpress, codex

I have used the wordpress `add_image_size` function on my theme `function.php`
and works fine but not for what I need.

I use the function in the soft proportional crop mode ex: `add_image_size('mySIZE', 420, 9999)`
witch means that the height of the image will change
and the file name will be like "image_name-420x230.jpg".

Because I'm getting the image via AJAX I need the file name, the width will be 420 but I don't know the height of each image that I upload.

what I need is a function that resize and give the file a name without the height
ex "image_name-420.jpg"

any idea on how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need the file name?  Create a wp_ajax function that returns the filename of the image based on the name that you gave that size.

Answer (score 0):

Well I find my way out.

My AJAX get a JSON what I have done is when I make my mysql query I loop through the array get the post_id.

as I have the post_id I can use the wp function get_the_post_thumbnail($posr_id, 'mySIZE')
after I have the html img with the size I want I get the src from the string and push in to results array and return the JSON.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($results); $i++) {
    $img = get_the_post_thumbnail($results[$i]['id'], 'mySIZE');
    preg_match( '@src="([^"]+)"@' , $img, $match );
    $src = array_pop($match);
    array_push($results[$i], $src);
}

return json_encode($results, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```